# CMake - SDL - Statically linked

Tags: linux, cmake, sdl

I have an application that I build on both windows and linux using cmake.  I want to distribute my linux version, but can't find a way via cmake to make it statically compile/include SDL.  I'd rather not assume/require any users have SDL already installed.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good idea to statically link SDL. If you care about easiness of installation for Linux, provide a `.deb` or `.rpm` package.

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-June/022256.html seems to provide some useful info on imported targets, specifically libraries and linkage control.  I did not include this as an answer because I believe the answer should actually explain how to do it.

Comment: Did you manage to do this?